# Sentence structure with adverbial

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Consider these sentences:

> They are good.
>   They are working.
>   They are eating lunch.

In first sentence `are` is a linking verb, and `good` is an adjective; so it has the form `S+V+C` (Subject + Verb + Complement).

I have a difficulty figuring out the roles of `are` and `working` in the second sentence. Clearly  `working` is not an adjective nor is it a noun, so it cannot be a subject complement. Any help?

I think the last sentence is pretty straightforward. Here `are` is helping verb, `eating` is the main verb, and lunch is the object; so it has the form `S + V + O` (Subject + Verb + Object).

Comment: Isn't it simply S+ V?

Comment: Oh, like `She went` ?

Comment: I should think so.

Comment: And, `They worked` or `They relaxed` -  in these, the subject itself is receiving the action. I think I get it. Thank you again:) You're awesome!

Comment: @TusharRaj If you had time and converted above comment to answer, I'd love to mark best :) (It might not look that big to you, but it really helped me).

Comment: "They are working" is ordinary intransitive (S-V) progressive aspect, (cf. the non-progressive equivalent "They work". "They are eating lunch" is ordinary monotransitive (S-V-Od), again in the progressive aspect. In the last two examples the matrix verb is "be" and what follows it is its complement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They are working.

`Are` is an auxiliary verb. `Working` is also a verb -- a present participle. There are no objects, complements or adverbials involved.

The structure would be S + V.

Comment: @rsadhvika: Please read Sir Lawler's remark above. This is the best answer you'll get.

Comment: (it's below now) Well, if we're specifying structures, it's actually `Su` + `VP`, and `VP` is `AuxVb` + `ActVb-ing` (those two structures together are called the "progressive construction", btw). `AuxVb` and `ActVb` are types of `V` (for that matter, `Su` is a type of `NP`) that behave differently. Only `AuxVb`s can invert with the subject in questions, for instance: _Are they working?_ but not *_Work they?_. Every form of _be_ (including _are_) is always `AuxVb`; some, but not all, uses of _have_  and _do_ are `AuxVb`, as are all uses of modal auxiliary verbs.